# Add InfoWindow, legend, scalebar and feature layer together

Tags: javascript, arcgis, infowindow, esri, arcgis-js-api

I am trying to use JavaScript to add in a legend, dual scalebar, feature layer and info window together in one html page. However, when I can add in the scalebar, feature layer and info window, the addition of the info window javascript codes will cause all my functions to disappear. However when I try to put in the info window first and then add in the legend, scalebar and feature layer, everything disappears as well. Below is my code for adding in the legend, feature layer and scalebar and then the info window. Everything's working except the info window, and I can't figure out why. Like is there a problem with the placement of codes in the JavaScript? A particular sequence I failed to follow?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- add in meta elements -->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
    <title>Mock Practical</title>
    <!-- reference styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.9/js/esri/css/esri.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.9/js/dojo/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
    <!-- reference arcGIS javascript -->
    <script src="http://js.arcgis.com/3.9/"></script>
    <style>
        html, body {
            height: 97%;
            width: 98%;
            margin: 1%;
        }

        #rightPane {
            width: 20%;
        }

        #legendPane {
            border: solid #97DCF2 1px;
        }
    </style>
    <!-- javascript -->
    <script>
     var map;
     require([
     "esri/map", "esri/dijit/InfoWindowLite",
     "esri/InfoTemplate", "esri/layers/FeatureLayer", "esri/dijit/Legend",
     "dojo/_base/array", "dojo/parser", "esri/dijit/Scalebar",
     "dijit/layout/BorderContainer", "dijit/layout/ContentPane",
    "dijit/layout/AccordionContainer",  "dojo/dom-construct", "dojo/domReady!"
     ], function(
     Map, InfoWindowLite, InfoTemplate, FeatureLayer, Legend,
     arrayUtils, parser,  Scalebar, domConstruct
     ) {
     parser.parse();
     map = new Map("map", {
     basemap:"topo",
     center: [-98.416, 39.781],
     zoom: 6
     });

      // scalebar
      var scalebar = new Scalebar({
          map: map,
          // "dual" displays both miles and kilmometers
          // "english" is the default, which displays miles
          // use "metric" for kilometers
          scalebarUnit: "dual", attachTo:"bottom-center"

        });

     // feature layer
    var featureLayer = new
     FeatureLayer("http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Census/MapServer/3", {
     mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND,
     outFields:["STATE_NAME", "SUB_REGION", "STATE_ABBR"]
     });
     //map.addLayer(featureLayer);


     //add the legend
     map.on("layers-add-result", function (evt) {
     var layerInfo = arrayUtils.map(evt.layers, function (layer, index) {
     return {layer:layer.layer, title:layer.layer.name};
     });
     if (layerInfo.length > 0) {
     var legendDijit = new Legend({
     map: map,
     layerInfos: layerInfo
     }, "legendDiv");
     legendDijit.startup();
     }
     });
     map.addLayers([featureLayer]);


     var legendFeature = new
    FeatureLayer("http://www.onemap.sg/ArcGIS/rest/services/TOC/MapServer/6", {
     mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND,
     outFields:["*"]
     });

     // infoWindow
     var infoWindow = new InfoWindowLite(null, domConstruct.create("div", null, null,
    map.root));
     infoWindow.startup();
     map.setInfoWindow(infoWindow);

     var template = new InfoTemplate();
    template.setTitle("<b>State name ${STATE_NAME} - State abbr ${STATE_ABBR}</b>");
    template.setContent("${SUB_REGION} is in district ${STATE_NAME}.");
    map.addLayer(featureLayer);
    map.infoWindow.resize(200,75);
     });

    </script>

</head>

<body class="claro">
    <div id="content" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/BorderContainer" data-dojo-props="design:'headline', gutters:true" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0;">
        <div id="rightPane" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'right'">
            <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/AccordionContainer">
                <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" id="legendPane" data-dojo-props="title:'Legend', selected:true">
                    <div id="legendDiv"></div>
                </div>
                <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="title:'Pane 2'">
                    This pane could contain tools or additional content
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="map" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'center'" style="overflow:hidden;">

        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some small faults in above snippet code. Below are the details.

1. forget to add "BorderContainer, ContentPane, AccordionContainer," before domConstruct
2. you were not adding that infotemplate object to the feature layer.

**Below is working code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- add in meta elements -->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
    <title>Mock Practical</title>
    <!-- reference styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.9/js/esri/css/esri.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.9/js/dojo/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
    <!-- reference arcGIS javascript -->
    <script src="http://js.arcgis.com/3.9/"></script>
    <style>
        html, body {
            height: 97%;
            width: 98%;
            margin: 1%;
        }

        #rightPane {
            width: 20%;
        }

        #legendPane {
            border: solid #97DCF2 1px;
        }
    </style>
    <!-- javascript -->
    <script>
        var map;
        require([
        "esri/map", "esri/dijit/InfoWindowLite",
        "esri/InfoTemplate", "esri/layers/FeatureLayer", "esri/dijit/Legend",
        "dojo/_base/array", "dojo/parser", "esri/dijit/Scalebar",
        "dijit/layout/BorderContainer", "dijit/layout/ContentPane",
       "dijit/layout/AccordionContainer", "dojo/dom-construct", "dojo/domReady!"
        ], function (
        Map, InfoWindowLite, InfoTemplate, FeatureLayer, Legend,
        arrayUtils, parser, Scalebar, BorderContainer, ContentPane, AccordionContainer, domConstruct
        ) {
            parser.parse();
            map = new Map("map", {
                basemap: "topo",
                center: [-98.416, 39.781],
                zoom: 6
            });

            // scalebar
            var scalebar = new Scalebar({
                map: map,
                // "dual" displays both miles and kilmometers
                // "english" is the default, which displays miles
                // use "metric" for kilometers
                scalebarUnit: "dual", attachTo: "bottom-center"

            });

            var template = new InfoTemplate("<b>State name ${STATE_NAME} - State abbr ${STATE_ABBR}</b>", "${SUB_REGION} is in district ${STATE_NAME}.");
            //template.setTitle("<b>State name ${STATE_NAME} - State abbr ${STATE_ABBR}</b>");
            //template.setContent("${SUB_REGION} is in district ${STATE_NAME}.");

          //  map.infoWindow.resize(200, 75);

            // feature layer
            var featureLayer = new FeatureLayer("http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Census/MapServer/3", {
                 mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND,
                 outFields: ["STATE_NAME", "SUB_REGION", "STATE_ABBR"],
                 infoTemplate: template
             });
              map.addLayer(featureLayer);


            //add the legend
            map.on("layers-add-result", function (evt) {
                var layerInfo = arrayUtils.map(evt.layers, function (layer, index) {
                    return { layer: layer.layer, title: layer.layer.name };
                });
                if (layerInfo.length > 0) {
                    var legendDijit = new Legend({
                        map: map,
                        layerInfos: layerInfo
                    }, "legendDiv");
                    legendDijit.startup();
                }
            });
            map.addLayers([featureLayer]);


            var legendFeature = new FeatureLayer("http://www.onemap.sg/ArcGIS/rest/services/TOC/MapServer/6", {
               mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND,
               outFields: ["*"]
           });

            // infoWindow
           // var infoWindow = new InfoWindowLite(null, domConstruct.create("div", null, null,
           //map.root));
           // infoWindow.startup();
           // map.setInfoWindow(infoWindow);


        });

    </script>

</head>

<body class="claro">
    <div id="content" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/BorderContainer" data-dojo-props="design:'headline', gutters:true" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0;">
        <div id="rightPane" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'right'">
            <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/AccordionContainer">
                <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" id="legendPane" data-dojo-props="title:'Legend', selected:true">
                    <div id="legendDiv"></div>
                </div>
                <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="title:'Pane 2'">
                    This pane could contain tools or additional content
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="map" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'center'" style="overflow:hidden;">

        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hey it works, thanks! could you elaborate though, how should i know the sequence to add in the require list?

Comment: one more thing while doing "require" you not need to follow any convention just when you are giving any alias name you need to follow same sequence... feel free to shoot ur queries if any clarifications required or i am not clear anywhere.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is a standard of dojo AMD structure... like how many widgets you require you have to give an alias name to it in same order...
Alias name may be anything xyz understandable to you however when you will you those dojo widget in your application you have to use those alias to initalize that widget.

**From Dojo Site:**

The foundation for "modern" Dojo is the require() function. It creates a closure of JavaScript code and provides it with the modules it needs to do the job as return variables passed as arguments to the function. Typically, the first argument is an array of module IDs (MIDs) and the second is the function. Within the closure of the require(), we reference the modules based on the variable name we declared in the argument. While we could call a module anything, there are some common conventions that are used and are usually noted in the [dojo Reference Guide.](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/modern_dojo/)

Modern Dojo means simply dojo AMD or dojo format 1.7 onward...

Hope this will help you :)